# CSS - responsive pointing at element

Tags: html, css, image, responsive

I don't have an idea even where to start. Like on the attached image I want to make a centered div (yellow rectangle) and two `img` elements that, regardless of the resolution (black rectangle), are pointing to the specific area of this div (red arrows). [image: example]

Comment: maybe by creating an image using photohop?

Comment: give position: relative to your parent ( means box ) and position: absolute to child ( arrow )

Comment: and where is your CSS & HTML?

Comment: You could look at putting the arrows in pseudo elements of the yellow rectangle, depending on whether the arrows are to affect what comes afterwards or not.

Comment: To be fully response, draw the arrows using e.g. svg.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use position: relative for the specific element (that you want to point at),
put the arrows (their html code) inside of the elemnt (that you want to point at) and then you can use position: absolute; with top, left, right, bottom properties to position the arrows relatively to the center point.